# Cannot display the ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

The `ListView` shows nothing when I want to set the adapter to display the items. To simplify the problem I put all codes in `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.result);       
    mListView = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.list);

    String[] items = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.result, R.id.test, items);

    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    handleIntent(getIntent());
}
```

My `result.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Theoretically the `ListView` should be displayed as item[1-3] soon after the `Activity` started but the screen prints nothing more than a black background and the title bar. I'm also confused by the fact that the program went wrong by passing the `R.id.list` to the third parameter of the `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LinearLayout` has its `orientation` set(by default) to `horizontal` and the `TextView` in that layout has its `width` set to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` so it uses all of its parent width. This will push your `ListView` element outside of the activity window and you'll not be able to see it. Modify your `result.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Also please **don't** reuse the activity layout as the `ListView` row layout, instead use a specific layout design for the rows only(without the `ListView` element).

Comment: That works! Much appreciated for that. I always forget some details like orientation...

Answer (score 2):

Your layout usage seems weird to me. You are trying to pass same layout for item as the layout for screen. Doing this causing your item to have ListView inside too, which is wrong. Change your Adapter as below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Comment: thx, I saw this usage on other question. If I set the 2nd parameter to the R.layout.result, it went wrong with the log:LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Answer (score 1):

You should call setListAdapter on the Activity and not directly call setAdapter on the listview directly.

So in your onCreate method do `setListAdapter(adapter);` instead of `mListView.setAdapter(adapter)`

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html):

> You must use ListFragment.setListAdapter() to associate the list with an adapter. Do not directly call ListView.setAdapter() or else important initialization will be skipped.

Comment: No, that's actually fine when you have a normal activity with a layout that contains more than the ListView. What you mean is a ListActivity, which (I guess) is not the case here.

Comment: Well that's a normal activity instead of listactivity

Comment: Hmm, think your right, there. I had the same problem with a ListFragment, but indeed the listActivity docs do not state the same line and if you are not using listActivity my answer does not apply. Be sure to check slukain's answer too, he has a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Set your Adapter like this..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.result, R.id.test, items);
```

in your code by

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

if you are not using custome layout for each listitem